# How can I read the value of a WpfCell using Coded UI? My current approach is throwing an exception

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I'm attempting to write a method to get the list of values in a particular column of a WPF data grid. Below is the code I've written so far:

```
public static List<string> GetColumnDataFromGrid(WpfWindow mainWindow, string gridAutomationId, string columnHeaderText)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss") + " | Waiting for custom control to be ready.");
    WpfCustom custom = new WpfCustom(mainWindow);
    custom.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCustom.PropertyNames.AutomationId, "userControlHeaderListView");
    custom.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCustom.PropertyNames.ClassName, "Uia.VoucherHeaderListView");
    custom.WaitForControlReady();
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss") + " | Custom control is ready.");

    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss") + " | Waiting for table [" + gridAutomationId + "] to be ready.");
    WpfTable table = new WpfTable(custom);
    table.SearchProperties.Add(WpfTable.PropertyNames.AutomationId, gridAutomationId);
    table.WaitForControlReady();
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss") + " | Table [" + gridAutomationId + "] is ready.");

    List<string> cellDataList = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < table.RowCount; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss") + " | Getting data from row [" + i + 1 + "].");
        WpfCell cell = new WpfCell(table);
        cell.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCell.PropertyNames.ColumnHeader, columnHeaderText);
        cell.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCell.PropertyNames.RowIndex, i.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss") + " | Waiting for cell to be ready.");
        if (cell.WaitForControlReady(15000))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss") + " | Cell is ready.");
            cellDataList.Add(new WpfText(cell).DisplayText);
        }
    }

    return cellDataList;
}
```

However when it get to cell.WaitForControlReady(15000), an exception is thrown:

> Test Name:    SetScStatusToBackToImportMouseTest (Data Row 0) Test
>   Outcome:  Failed Result Message:   Test method
>   CodedUI.ApplicationFeatureTest threw exception: 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException:
>   Automation Playback Engine was not able to find the custom control
>   userControlHeaderListView in - custom control userControl. Additional
>   Details:  TechnologyName:  'UIA' FrameworkId:  'WPF' ControlType: 
>   'Custom' ClassName:  'Uia.VoucherHeaderListView' AutomationId: 
>   'userControlHeaderListView'  --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has
>   been returned from a call to a COM component. Result StandardOutput:
>   2016/09/06 - 17:13:04 | Waiting for custom control to be ready.
>   2016/09/06 - 17:13:13 | Custom control is ready. 2016/09/06 - 17:13:13
>   | Waiting for table [MainDatagridView] to be ready. 2016/09/06 -
>   17:13:14 | Table [MainDatagridView] is ready. 2016/09/06 - 17:13:14 |
>   Getting data from row [01]. 2016/09/06 - 17:13:14 | Waiting for cell
>   to be ready.

I attempted to verify the value of a single cell using the coded ui test builder tool and it worked. I created a path to the row following the same search properties which was used by the test builder tool.

I'd appreciate it greatly if someone could point out why this is happening or even suggest an alternative.

Comment: Can you be able to get the value of one cell with this code?. I mean without using for loop?

Comment: @RajeshS Thanks for the suggestion but sadly it didn't work.

Comment: how do you call this method? may i see that code as well.. ?

Comment: @RajeshS I called the methods using: 
List<string> archiveNosList = Utilities.GetColumnDataFromGrid(base.MainWindow, InvoiceListPage.InvoiceListGrid, "Archive no.");

Comment: Which step does your automation fail exaclty? i still have doubt that it fails at cell.WaitForControlReady(15000). because it must have failed before this. looks like it is failing because it is unable to find the Custom control. please check and and tell where it fails.

Comment: @RajeshS That's where it fails. According to the console output, the message prior to the wait is the last one that is printed and when I tried debugging it doesn't get pass the "cell.WaitForControlReady(15000)" line.